# Sending a pulse from alternating constant output

Tags: capacitor, resistors, integrated-circuit, logic-gates, breadboard

I have an overlapping XOR gate which alternated from 0 to 1 whenever one of the inputs is turned on. Basically, it's off when there are even high input and on when there are odd high input. The problem with this is I'm only able to send a pulse when the said overlapping XOR gate goes from low to high. How can I also send a pulse when the output goes from low to high. I tried simulating using resistor capacitor but it always fails and I'm not sure why.

Comment: Rewrite the question, this time in English.  This gibberish is too annoying to read.  Also, actually ask a question.  This is not a show and tell site.  Closing this mess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you need an XOR gate edge detector: -

[image]

I would use a schmitt trigger version of the XOR gate.

For reference, maybe you have used an OR or AND gate and this is why you don't get pulses on both edge transitions: -

[image]

---

Added section - here's the circuit the OP posted as a comment: -

[image]

And my advice was "You don't need the inverters but you do need pull-down resistors on gate inputs connected to switches. You need pull-down resistors because without them the inputs would float to an unknown value rendering the circuit unstable and unpredictable."

Comment: I'll have an XOR gate as shown this one then I'll input than to the schmitt trigger, am I right?

Comment: Sorry I didn't follow what you were asking.

Comment: What I mean is, what logic gate shall I use after using this XOR gate?

Comment: @OrlandoLewis your question appears to be about extracting a pulse whenever the input changes and, that is done with an XOR gate (as shown in my answer). As to what logic gate you use afterwards I can only ask, what logic function do you require - there's nothing in your question about anything else so I cannot answer.

Comment: So I've tried simulating this circuit. The said overlapping XOR gates are like parity generators. So there's an output and let's call that T. I connected T to a resistor then to a capacitor as shown in the figure. The wire before the capacitor and after the resistor is then connected to an inverted schmitt trigger then I reconnected it again to another inverted schmitt trigger so I can have a positive pulse. The output T is then connected to an XOR gate together with the output from the schmitt trigger. I encountered another problem, gates exploding.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm just not following what you describe so please post an image or supply a link to an image of your circuit. It does sound incorrect what you are attempting.

Comment: Here is a link of my sample circuit with 3 input. https://www.dropbox.com/s/vqr9l49gs23eql5/PULSE.JPG?dl=0  Am I doing it correctly?

Comment: You don't need the inverters but you do need pull-down resistors on gate inputs connected to switches.

Comment: Unfortunately, even upon adding those pull-down resistors, the gates are still exploding.

Comment: Nevermind, I was able to make it work, the position of the resistor in the breaboard was incorrect. But may I just ask, what if I didn't use pull up resistors?

Comment: You need pull-down resistors because without them the inputs would float to an unknown value rendering the circuit unstable and unpredictable.

Comment: If you are happy with this answer, please consider formally accepting it. If there is something that remains unanswered from the question, please let me know so I can correct it.

Answer (score 0):

The great [Glen Chenier](http://www.edn.com/electronics-blogs/tales-from-the-cube/4327332/The-case-of-the-stolen-capacitor) passed away in 2016 but his EDN articles remain.

[Figure 15 in this one](http://www.edn.com/Home/PrintView?contentItemId=4423513) is probably what you need.

In typical Chenier style the whole article is a fun read.